# Brew command not found on high seirra

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am unable to run homebrew on OSX high sierra.
I have mistakenly deleted the .local folder from Users/username. I previously used flutter which I deleted and also removed its path.

Answer (score 0):

Best advise would be to simply reinstall homebrew, using the instructions on the homepage: https://brew.sh/

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Comment: already done that a thousand times everything works fine i get this in between
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist

Comment: Do you need to reinstall Xcode and the Xcode CLI tools - https://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/